# SharePoint 2010 - Adding filter to refinement panel

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I know there are threads out there about making changes to the refinement panel and they have so far been very helpful but now I have a question that I need a bit more assistance with.

I've created a new filter for the refinement panel. That worked very fine.
I can see the filter, when I perform a search.

[image]

But when I click on the new filter, all search results disappear and it just says: "We did not find any results for ".

[image]

I can see that the url gets my created filter attached:

results.aspx?...&r=filterfield%3D%22True%22

I have created a managed metadata property and added the field to the search results (search core results webpart). 
What I'm doing wrong? Why it doesn't work? 
Any hints?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why did you add a filter field to the search results web part? What does that have to do with the refiner?

Comment: No, sorry, I added the field itself, not a filter to the search results. I read it somewhere, that otherwise the filter won't work. I sounded strange to me, but I needed the field there anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. I forgot to start a full crawl after creating the managed metadata field.